# katapayadi sutra - some melakarta raagas' numberings that I can't understand

Tags: vedas

The KaTapayadi system hinges upon the table below:

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ka | Ka | ga | Ga | ~ga | ca | Ca | ja | Ja | ~ja |
| Ta | Tha | Da | Dha | Na | ta | tha | da | dha | na |
| pa | Pa | ba | Ba | ma |  |  |  |  |  |
| ya | ra | la | va | sha | Sha | sa | ha |  |  |

I have come to understand the numbering of the 72 Melakarta raagas are roughly as follows: The second consonant of the raaga name determines the first digit and the first consonant determines the second digit.

E.g.,
a) kanakAMgi is the first, or the 01^th raaga. The first letter ka is in column header 1 so that's the second digit, and the second letter na is in column header 0 so that's the first digit, hence the raaga number is 01.
b) similarly chalanATa is the 36th raaga (cha for 6 and la for 3)

However, what throws me off is when one of the first two letters is a combination of consonants (vottAkShara in Kannada). E.g., kra, jyO, rya, Dva, etc. Because in such cases one of the consonants in the combination is preferred over the other. What precise rule is used to make this preference is still unclear. Could someone throw light on this?

On closely investigating, I find that there are 10 such cases:

```
tna in ratnangi (raaga 02), between ta and na, na was chosen
kra in chakravaka (raaga 16), between ka and ra, ka was chosen
rya in sUryakAMti (raaga 17), between ra and ya, ya was chosen
Dvi in ShaDvidamArga (raaga 46), between Da and va, va was chosen
vya in divyamaNi (raaga 48), between va and ya, va was chosen
shva in vishvaMBari (raaga 54), between sha and va, sha was chosen
hma in sihmEMdramadhyamam (raaga 57), between ha and ma, ma was chosen
rma in dharmAvati (raaga 59), between ra and ma, ma was chosen
tra in citrAMbari (raaga 66), between ta and ra, ta was chosen
jyA in jyOtisvarUpiNi (raaga 68), between ja and ya, ja was chosen
```

The rule is sure to be dependent on whether or not one of the letters in the combo is among ya, ra, la, va. However, I'm trying to determine the rule. Every rule I try fits at most nine of the above ten cases.

```
For example, I thought the following: If the latter consonant in the
combination is among ya, ra, la, va, the former should be preferred, and otherwise
the latter should be preferred. This worked for all raagas except the 46th one 
ShaDvidamArga where the latter was preferred over the former, an exception to the
rule I thought held.
```

Any help answering above is appreciated.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be related with music & not with religion.

Comment: Ok. I'll post it on music.stackexchange.com